# Safari (5) or Mac OS X (10.6 Snow Leopard): Is past HTTP Post data stored?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, safari

In either Safari 5 (history intact) or Snow Leopard, is there a way to view a sent HTTP Post request? A session expired and I am looking for the data that was posted (and lost).

Answer (score -1):

No. Post data is deliberately never saved.

It's the most common way to send private data to a server, such as passwords every time you log in. It will never be saved unless the server writes it to a database somewhere.